# How can i set "Options" of item with paypal php sdk?

Tags: php, paypal

I have integerated paypal in to my app and everything works, but

I need to add options info to my purchase like, if I buy a shirt, I can set the size and color.

I went through documentation and found no info or examples, nothing also on the web. 
Does anyone know how to do this?
Here is some of my code that sets the transaction:

```
$item = new PayPal\Api\Item();
    $payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
    $amount = new PayPal\Api\Amount();
    $payment = new PayPal\Api\Payment();
    $details = new PayPal\Api\Details();
    $itemList = new PayPal\Api\ItemList();
    $transaction = new PayPal\Api\Transaction();
    $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();

    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    // Item
    $item->setName($product['Product']['name'])
            ->setCurrency('EUR')
            ->setQuantity($quantity)

            ->setPrice($product['Product']['price']);

    $itemList->setItems(array($item));

    //Details
    $details->setShipping('00.0')
            ->setTax('00.0')
            ->setSubtotal($cost);

    //Amount
    $amount->setCurrency('EUR')
            ->setTotal($cost)
            ->setDetails($details);



    //Transaction
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setDescription('Description text')
            ->setItemList($itemList);

    //Payment
    $payment->setIntent('sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    //Redirect URLs
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('some.website.com/')
            ->setCancelUrl('some.website.com/cancel');

    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
```

Where should I set options? There are no such setOptions method anywhere in the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inform the buyer what he is buying, i concatenate the meta data to the items name like that:

```
    $item->setName($product['Product']['name'].' '.$product['Product']['size'].' '.$product['Product']['color']);
```

So the buyer will see the details also on paypal.

Answer (score 0):

@dappler is kind of right.

1. If you wish to show the information to the buyer, I would append that to the name.
2. If you just want it to be for your personal records, you could use `setDescription` field that is exposed in the REST API. When you do a `get` on it, you should receive that, and act accordingly.